# How to deduce a type by remove_cv function (const volatile int* vs const volatile int vs int * const volatile)

Tags: c++, templates, constants

There is a function "remove_cv" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) to remove constant and volatile.

My question is why it is possible to remove from "const volatile int" to "int"
and from "int * const volatile" to "int*" but "const volatile int*" is the same as before remove.

```
The possible code is from the site
template< class T >
struct remove_cv {
    typedef typename std::remove_volatile<typename std::remove_const<T>::type>::type type;
};

template< class T > struct remove_const          { typedef T type; };
template< class T > struct remove_const<const T> { typedef T type; };


template< class T > struct remove_volatile             { typedef T type; };
template< class T > struct remove_volatile<volatile T> { typedef T type; };
```

I can't understand the rules for the pointer type deduction.
Can you guys show me the way for/how compiler possibly do it?
Are there rules for the deduction?

Comment: The const/volatile is top level for one type and not for the other

Answer (score 2):

As per the description, these classes remove the **topmost** cv-qualifiers.

Writing the qualifiers on the right of what they modify can help explain this (`^` marks the top level):

```
int const volatile
    ^
int* const volatile
     ^
int const volatile*
                   ^
```

In the last example the top level has no cv-qualifiers, so there is nothing to remove.

The details of cv-conversions are in [conv.qual], although it isn't particularly easy to understand. The gist of it is:

- The top level cv-qualifer can be implicitly converted to any combination
- At any other level cv-qualifiers must be preserved if present
- `const` must be added to every level above a level where the cv-qualifiers differ.

The standard gives a good example of how the last rule prevents inadvertently changing `const` objects:

```
int main() {
  const char c = 'c';
  char* pc;
  const char** pcc = &pc; // #1: not allowed
  *pcc = &c;
  *pc = 'C';              // #2: modifies a const object
}
```

The declaration of `pcc` above is invalid, as the cv-qualifers at the lowest level are different. To be valid it must have an additional `const` added to every level above the conflict (although not necessarily the top level):

```
const char* const* pcc = &pc;
```

This extends to as many levels as necessary, as well as to volatile:

```
char** pc;
const char*** pcc = &pc;             // Invalid
const char* const* const* pcc = &pc; // Ok

char** pc;
char* volatile** pcc = &pc;          // Nope
char* volatile* const* pcc = &pc;    // OK
```